# Difference between 2 dates in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I want to be able to find the difference in seconds between two TDateTime variables in Delphi 5. In the later versions of delphi there are helper functions [SecondsBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween) to do this. Is there a better way to do this other than rolling my own (Finding the difference of the two variables as a double then converting them to seconds)?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to 2013, dear time traveler! Just to give you a quick update: the world didn't change much in the meantime, but there are newer Delphi versions. Oh, and 2013-1999 = 14 years. Or do you need that in seconds? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Secs := Round(SecsPerMin * MinsPerHour * HoursPerDay * Abs(Time2 - Time1));
```

Comment: So rolling my own it is! Thanks

Comment: Just to note - those constants don't exist within SysUtils in Delphi 5.

Comment: I ended up having to use Round rather than Trunc since at 6 minutes difference (e.g. date1 = 0 date2 = 0.004167) this will return 359 not 360

Comment: You *always* have to round when converting from float to integer. Trunc cuts away the decimals, but this is hardly ever what you want.

Comment: @alzaimer Depends on the task at hand. Getting whole number of days from a date time is Trunc. For this question it has to be Round.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes another way of doing the same. Tested in Delphi 5

```
var
  Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(datetime2-datetime1, Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);
end;
```